# Slider is not working with Bootstrap-RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I load my slider with the normal bootrap css fine it works fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

but when I load it with the rtl css file - the photos are changing but the slide animation is not working for some reason

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css">
```

I'm using the RTL files from the original bootstrap repo.

My slider:

```
    <!-- My Carousel     -->   
     <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide">

            <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">

                    <div class="item active">
                              <img src="gallery/img1.jpg" alt="IMG1">
                              <div class="carousel-caption" >  סלייד ראשון .   <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm ">לפרטים</button>  </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="item ">
                              <img src="gallery/img2.jpg" alt="IMG2">
                              <div class="carousel-caption">  סלייד שני .   </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item ">
                            <img src="gallery/img3.jpg" alt="IMG3">
                           <div class="carousel-caption">  סלייד שלישי ואחרון .   </div>
                  </div>

          </div>

     </div><!-- End of My Carousel     -->
```

Comment: Are you using the latest versions from both?

Comment: @Spokey Yes, I downloaded both from the same git in the same time.

Comment: @Unknownman I'm not sure what fiddle is. Where do I get it from?

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is editing the carousel container direction

```
<style>
#carousel_container, #or_beyond_the_container_if_needed {
direction: ltr;
}
</style>
```

this will change carousel direction

annotation: This solution will work with any carousel or slider

Answer (score 1):

you should use this code.

```
.carousel-control-prev{
    right:auto;
}
.carousel-item {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do a condition first to load bootstrap rtl only on language that you need to.
then make a custom style with these changes , please make sure to call this custom style only when you need it, 'cause will cause you incompatible with ltr.

```
   .carousel-item {
        margin-right: initial;
    }
    .carousel-control-next {
        right: initial;
    }
```